# Asterisk ConfBridge disable all sounds from conference (BabyMonitor)

Tags: asterisk, pjsip

i am trying to get a Baby Monitor working with 2 phones on Asterisk (chan_pjsip) extensions.

i tryed this config in /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf:

```
;Baby Monitor Conference
exten => 222,1,NoOp(>>>> CONNECTING TO MONITOR MODE FROM REMOTE PHONE <<<<)
exten => 222,n,Set(CONFBRIDGE(user,announce_join_leave)=no)
exten => 222,n,Set(CONFBRIDGE(user,startmuted)=yes)
exten => 222,n,ConfBridge(1)

exten => 333,1,NoOp(>>>> CONNECTING TO MONITOR MODE FROM BABY'S ROOM <<<<)
exten => 333,n,Set(CONFBRIDGE(user,announce_join_leave)=no)
exten => 333,n,Set(CONFBRIDGE(announcement)=no)
exten => 333,n,Set(CONFBRIDGE(user,quiet)=yes)
exten => 333,n,ConfBridge(1)
```

But on extension 333 (Baby´s room) there are still join and leave notifications played.

Any hints, what has to be done that sounds will be completely suppressed on extension 333?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Use settings in confbridge.conf

In your example you set something to profile "user" after that not use it in conference call.